# Не добавляются данные в базу данных Sqlite3 PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, база-данных, pyqt5, sqlite3

В чем может быть проблема? База данных создается, но новые данные в нее не записываются.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'mysql.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.10.1
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sqlite3


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def messagebox(self,title,message):
        mess = QtWidgets.QMessageBox()
        mess.setWindowTitle(title)
        mess.setText(message)
        mess.setStandardButtons(QtWidgets.QmeesageBox.Ok)
        mess.exec_()
    def signup(self):
        name = self.lineEdit.text()
        username = self.lineEdit_2.text()
        password = self.lineEdit_3.text()
        mobile = self.lineEdit_4.text()
        conn = sqlite3.connect('youtube.db')
        conn.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS signup(name TEXT,username TEXT,pasword TEXT,mobile INTEGER)")
        cur = conn.cursor()
        conn.close()
        query = ("insert into signup(name,username,pasword,mobile) values(?,?,?,?)",(name,username,password,mobile))
        data = cur.execute(query,(name,username,pasword,mobile))
        if (data):
               self.messagebox("congrat")
        conn.close()
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 100, 58, 18))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 160, 71, 18))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 210, 58, 18))
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 250, 58, 18))
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 90, 113, 32))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 150, 113, 32))
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.lineEdit_3 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 200, 113, 32))
        self.lineEdit_3.setObjectName("lineEdit_3")
        self.lineEdit_4 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 240, 113, 32))
        self.lineEdit_4.setObjectName("lineEdit_4")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 330, 88, 34))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.signup)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 30))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "name"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "username"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "password"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "mobile"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Кст, не добавляйте лишние круглые скобки, например в `if (data):` :)

Comment: И лучше не править `Ui_MainWindow`, добавляя к нему логику. А сделать новый класс, например, MainWindow, и применить к нему `Ui_MainWindow`, пример: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/5391958f6debe4ee2192191d67316a72353f9d23/qt__pyqt__pyside__pyqode/schedule_and_QThread.py#L76 (если возникнут проблемы, могу подсказать как именно)

Comment: ваш пример содержит много опечаток, пожалуйста проверяйте код прежде чем его публиковать. Строки, которые содержат ошибки: `mess.setStandardButtons(QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Ok)`,  `conn.close()` - указан дважды, `data = cur.execute(query,(name, username, password, mobile))`, `self.messagebox("title", "congrat")` и это без учета того, что вам написал @gil9red

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вызывайте коммит данных. Данные, что вы добавляете в базу попадают в кэш, а коммит из кэша передает данные в базу данных.

Перед `conn.close()` вызывайте `conn.commit()`

---

Еще мне кажется в `query` лишние данные, после строки с запросом.

Так должно работать:

```
sql = "insert into signup(name, username, pasword, mobile) values(?, ?, ?, ?)"
data = cur.execute(sql, (name, username, pasword, mobile))
```

Answer (score 0):

Огромное спасибо **gil9red** за представленное решение.

Сначала после того как внес ваши изменения ничего не получилось, затем решил дать все разрешения файлу с базой данных, а именно: "**sudo chmod -R 777 youtube.db**" все заработало!